# Auto populating Outlook email from MS Access Form

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-access-2016

I have a table called ClientListtbl and a form called ClientListfrm.
on the form there is a click button to automatically generate an email. please see code below

```
Private Sub Command20_Click()

    Dim LastName As Variant
    Dim Email As Variant
    Dim Notes As Variant
    Dim Insurer As Variant
    Dim Premium As Variant
    Dim RenewalDate As Date
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object

    LastName = Forms("ClientListfrm").LastName
    Email = Forms("ClientListfrm").EmailAddress
    Notes = Forms("ClientListfrm").Notes
    Insurer = Forms("ClientListfrm").Insurer
    Premium = Forms("ClientListfrm").Premium

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objEmail
     .To = Email
     .Subject = "transfer " & LastName & " from James"
     .HTMLBody = Insurer & _
     Premium & _
     RenewalDate & _
     Notes
     .Send
End With

    Set objEmail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'd like the email to not send automatically so it can be reviewed by the user before sending, but I can't seem to figure how to change that.

And in the HTMLBody, i'd like there to be a new line for each field but all the examples I've seen and tried don't work.

And the RenewalDate in the HTMLBody displays in the email as 20000:00:00 and not the date shown on the form.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Display` instead of `.Send`.

If you want to send HTML, you need to build HTML. E.g.

```
.HTMLBody = "<p>" & Insurer & "</p>" & _
     "<p>" & Premium & "</p>"
```

etc. Or build your string with `vbCrLf` separators, and then use `HtmlEncode()` on the result.

You don't set `RenewalDate` in your code. Use the `Format()` function, if necessary.

Comment: thank you for your help. all sorted except the RenewalDate, I'll keep working on that.